# How to differentiate three POST methods with same parameter in Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have three POST Action methods in my controller

1. PostProjectData([FromBody] MyObject object)
2. PostCustData([FromBody] MyObject object)
3. PostBookData([FromBody] MyObject object)

So how will the Web API identify the each method???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Totally agree with *Stay Foolish*. You should separate your concerns into three different controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you think that is a good design for that in Web API platform?

I think it will be better to have

ProjectController which will take care of the PostProjectData([FromBody] MyObject object)

CustController which will take care of the PostCustData([FromBody] MyObject object)

BookController which will take care of the PostBookData([FromBody] MyObject object)

If you really want to go with this way, you can setup the routing in the following way.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                string.Empty,
                "yourroute1",
                new { controller = "yourcontroller", action = "PostProjectData" },
                new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get.Post) }
            );
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                string.Empty,
                "yourroute2",
                new { controller = "yourcontroller", action = "PostCustData" },
                new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get.Post) }
            );
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                string.Empty,
                "yourroute3",
                new { controller = "yourcontroller", action = "PostBookData" },
                new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get.Post) }
            );
```

But I reckon you should redesign the controller since the resouce is Project, Cust and Book. they should have their own controller. Is that right?

Comment: I would agree to separate the posts to different controllers as they are different actions.